# Nginx returning 405 on POST requests for Dockerized React + Vite

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, vite

I'm trying to dockerize an Vite+React+Typescript app that i've started developing, but i'm receiving 405 on Post requests...

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And this is my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  include mime.types;

  server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried adding

> error_page  405 = $uri;

On the nginx.conf file, but now instead of throwing a 405, it just returns the content of my index file...

Any tips on how to fix this?